# trying to get knockout js to check if data has come every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to call the function which posts the ajax request to check the database, every 10 seconds to see if the required information I want has arrived or not, if the required information has not arrived for 60 seconds, I just want to exit the function.
The problem I am having right now is that, my function doesnt call `self.startInstantorCheck` every 10 seconds, and then exits to the end after 60 seconds.
Here is the function

```
self.startInstatorCheck = function(){
                self.instatorStarts(true);
                var MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS = 1 * 60 * 1000;
                var POST_INTERVAL_MS = 10 * 1000;
                var timeoutTime = null;
                $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/check_instantor_field/' + auth,
                      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                   })
                .done(function(userinfo) {
                    if (timeoutTime == null) {
                      // Start of the timeout cycle:
                      timeoutTime = Date.now() + MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS;
                    }
                    if (userinfo.instantor_request > 12) {
                      self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Instantor data gathered');
                    } else {
                      if (Date.now() < MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS) {
                        setTimeout(self.startInstatorCheck(), POST_INTERVAL_MS);
                      } else {
                          self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Please go through instantor to ');
                          self.instatorStarts(true);
                          self.magicInstantorbtn2(true);
                      }
                    }
                 })
               .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
               })
               .always(function(data){               
               });
        }
I am using knockout js, so would be great if the answers or help are related to knockout js.
```

Comment: You're saying it doesn't call every 10 and it doesn't end after 60? Or it doesn't call every 10, but after 60 seconds it ends?

Comment: @PatrickMotard What I am trying to say is that, it should call the function ever 10 seconds to see if it has got the instantor_request > 12, and after 60 seconds if there is no result for instantor_request , then it should just exit the function and do this steps 
`self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Please go through instantor to ');
                          self.instatorStarts(true);
                          self.magicInstantorbtn2(true);`

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. I know what your goal is. What I'm asking for is clarification on what isn't working. What part doesn't work. Does it keep polling after 60 seconds? Does it not poll at all?

Comment: Actually it doesnt even start the 10 seconds check and goes directly to the last step, I just saw your codes will try it out now. 
@PatrickMotard

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here's your code simplified to reduce nesting and provide clarity through naming.

```
           self.startInstatorCheck = function(){
                self.instatorStarts(true);
                var MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS = 1 * 60 * 1000;
                var POST_INTERVAL_MS = 10 * 1000;
                var timeoutTime = null;
                $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/check_instantor_field/' + auth,
                      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                   })
                .done(function(userinfo) {
                    // please use === not == 
                    // == doesn't always do what you want it to do, NEVER use it
                    timeoutTime = timeoutTime === null ?  
                        Date.now() + MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS :
                        timeoutTime;

                    var pleaseNameMe = userinfo.instantor_request > 12
                    if (pleaseNameMe) {
                      return self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Instantor data gathered');
                    }

                    var expired = Date.now() < MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS
                    if (!expired) {
                      return setTimeout(self.startInstatorCheck(), POST_INTERVAL_MS);
                    }

                    self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Please go through instantor to ');
                    self.instatorStarts(true);
                    self.magicInstantorbtn2(true);

               })
               .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
               })
               .always(function(data){               
               });
        }
```

Secondly, your question has been solved before, knockoutjs or not. [Here is a wonderful article](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling) that explains how to do polling in javascript using timeout. It recommends using promises. I strongly agree. (They can and should be used in conjunction with knockout js.) A contrived example directly from the blog:

```
// The polling function
function poll(fn, timeout, interval) {
    var dfd = new Deferred();
    var endTime = Number(new Date()) + (timeout || 2000);
    interval = interval || 100;

    (function p() {
            // If the condition is met, we're done! 
            if(fn()) {
                dfd.resolve();
            }
            // If the condition isn't met but the timeout hasn't elapsed, go again
            else if (Number(new Date()) < endTime) {
                setTimeout(p, interval);
            }
            // Didn't match and too much time, reject!
            else {
                dfd.reject(new Error('timed out for ' + fn + ': ' + arguments));
            }
    })();

    return dfd.promise;
}

// Usage:  ensure element is visible
poll(function() {
    return document.getElementById('lightbox').offsetWidth > 0;
}, 2000, 150);
```

Comment: I tried your code, it did not work, I am not sure why, it doesnt call the function more than onces, it just checks if the value is > 12,and since it isnt it just exists.

Comment: My reiteration of your code is just cleaning it up. I didn't change any functionality in it. I was just trying to show you a cleaner way of writing what your wrote. The example below it is an example that you can use to create your own 'correct' solution. I'm giving you the means to solve this problem yourself, not solving it for you. "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: yea i understand , but i was doing this for the past 10 hours and I am super tensed and frustrated, would be great if you could help me solve it too

Answer (score 1):

there are few mistakes in your code.

compare this with yours to see the changes

```
self.startInstatorCheck = function() {
    self.instatorStarts(true);
    var t = new Date();
    var timeoutTime = t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 60)
    var interval = 10 * 1000;

    function instatorCheck() {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/check_instantor_field/' + auth,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(userinfo) {
                if (userinfo.instantor_request > 12) {
                    self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Instantor data gathered');
                } else {
                    if (new Date() < timeoutTime) {
                        setTimeout(instatorCheck, interval);
                    } else {
                        self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Please go through instantor to ');
                        self.instatorStarts(true);
                        self.magicInstantorbtn2(true);
                    }
                }
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
            })
            .always(function(data) {});
    }
    instatorCheck();
}
```

Comment: Can i ask why are you using two functions? Cant it be done with one?

Comment: cuz you need a global `timeoutTime` for all local `instatorCheck` calls. also this will run `instatorCheck` for every 10 secs, not `startInstatorCheck`

Comment: I tried your code, but it does not call the function every 10 minutes or wait for 60 seconds before going to the please go through instatotor to , it just directly goes there.

Comment: the reason it goes there because of `new Date() > timeoutTime` so check and make sure why `timeoutTime` is not currentTime + 60 sec

Comment: is new Date not a js function? I got it from w3school, sorry I am new to coding so I try to get things from here and there, might be great if you could help me out

Comment: [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is js function, and `new Date()` and `Date.now()` both are same

Comment: Yea its pretty hard for me to understand why the function is not following the set time at all..I am not sure at all.